# How can I loop through an array of letters and return the first consecutive consonants in the array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

I'm trying to remove only the first consecutive consonants from the array so it returns  ["e","l","l","o"]

```
arr=["h","e","l","l","o"]
vowel=["a","e","i","o","u"]
consonants=[];

for ( i in arr){
    if(vowel.indexOf(arr[i]) =-1 ) {
       consonants+=arr[i];
       arr= arr.slice(consonants.length)
    }else { return arr }   

}
```

Comment: your for loops looks funky...try**for(i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I might have interpreted your question wrong, but I took it as meaning "return an array with all the leading consonants removed".

Anyway, this seems like a pretty good use-case for regular expressions:

```
var arr=["h","e","l","l","o"]

// hat-tip to @minitech in the comments for improving this line...
var result = arr.join('').replace(/^[^aeiou]+/, '').split('');

console.log(result);
// [ 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o' ]
```

**Explanation:**

- `arr.join('')` converts the array into a string
- `.replace(/^[^aeiou]+/, '')` removes any leading non-vowel characters
- `.split('')` converts the result into an array of characters

Comment: `.replace(/^[aeiou]+/, '')` might be a bit simpler.

Comment: lol, how true. "something something about the forest and the trees..."

Comment: You understood the question correctly and your answer makes sense to me the Regex stuff is pretty niffty, thanks !

Answer (score 1):

In the loop here,

```
for ( i in arr){
```

you should use a normal `for` loop instead; `for in` is for iterating over properties and iterates in [an arbitrary order](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-ordinary-object-internal-methods-and-internal-slots-enumerate).

In the condition here,

```
if(vowel.indexOf(arr[i]) =-1 )
```

you’ll need to use `==` to check for equality; `=` is only for assignment. (`===` is also a good option, for strict equality.)

In the statement here,

```
consonant+=arr[i];
```

you’re converting `consonant` from an array to a string the first time around (assuming `consonants` was just a typo). Either is fine if you’re only using its `length` property, but you should be consistent and either initialize it with the empty string `''` or append to it using the `.push()` method.

In the reassignment of `arr` here,

```
arr= arr.slice(consonant.length)
```

you’re losing the original object being enumerated, which will skew your indexes for future iterations. You’re also slicing `consonant.length` off each time, which will result in total removals of 1, 3, 6, 10, and so on characters. It’s probably best to break out of the loop and do the slicing once at the end.

You should also declare your variables if you aren’t already. All told,

```
var arr = ["h", "e", "l", "l", "o"];
var vowels = ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u"];
var consonants = [];

for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    var c = arr[i];

    if (vowels.indexOf(c) == -1) {
        consonants.push(c);
    } else {
        // using `i` in place of `consonants.length` here would work just as well
        return arr.slice(consonants.length);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your actually preety close the correct function would look like

```
arr=["h","e","l","l","o"];
vowel=["a","e","i","o","u"];
consonants=[];

for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
    if(vowel.indexOf(arr[i]) == -1 ) {
       consonants.push(arr[i]);
       arr= arr.slice(consonants.length)
}else { return arr }   

}
```

Your for loop was a little off and your constonant variable was named 2 different things in your function...you have **constonant** and **constanants**

Comment: im functional style would be much better for this (with use .some() )

Comment: @PawełSmołka: Functional style would use `findIndex`, not `some`, and that’s not available in most browsers or JavaScript engines in general today.

Comment: I meant to use it on serverside, but fact is ~Tormod Smith might not use node.js etc so my advice could not be a good one. Still I would use .map and .some with no for loop.

Answer (score 0):

Try array.filter - like this:

```
var arr=["h","e","l","l","o"],
vowel=["a","e","i","o","u"],
first_consonant_found = false;

var consonants = arr.filter(function(ele){
    if (vowel.indexOf(ele) == -1 && !first_consonant_found){
        first_consonant_found = true;
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }

})
```